# How do you properly paste in code from an #include in Arduino IDE?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a short program that controls an RGB LED strip. Because the library is so small, I want to put it into a single file so it can simply be copied/pasted into a project.

Everything's working fine except for a single include which doesn't work when copied directly into the code.

I've tried to directly copy and paste in the code from `#include "cRGB.h"`, which happens to be a simple struct. definition (`struct cRGB { uint8_t g; uint8_t r; uint8_t b; };`).

See the full code below.

It is my understanding that `#include` simply 'copies' code from a file directly into the document. If that is the case, why does this code fail to compile?

```
#include "cRGB.h"

class WS2812 {
public: 
  WS2812(uint16_t num_led);
  ~WS2812();
  
  void setOutput(uint8_t pin);
  
  cRGB get_crgb_at(uint16_t index);
  uint8_t set_crgb_at(uint16_t index, cRGB px_value);
  uint8_t set_subpixel_at(uint16_t index, uint8_t offset, uint8_t px_value);

  void sync();

private:
  uint16_t count_led;
  uint8_t *pixels;

  void ws2812_sendarray_mask(uint8_t *array,uint16_t length, uint8_t pinmask,uint8_t *port, uint8_t *portreg);

  const volatile uint8_t *ws2812_port;
  volatile uint8_t *ws2812_port_reg;
  uint8_t pinMask; 
};



WS2812 LED(4); // 1 LED
  
cRGB value1;
cRGB value2;
cRGB value3;
cRGB value4;

void setup() {
  LED.setOutput(3); // Digital Pin 9
}

void loop() {
  value1.b = 0; value1.g = 255; value1.r = 255; // RGB Value
  LED.set_crgb_at(0, value1); // Set value at LED found at index 0
  LED.sync(); // Sends the value to the LED
  delay(500); // Wait 500 ms
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
/var/folders/fr/vj8c52911yg97mycb0d8xjk00000gn/T//ccoFxRCe.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `setup':
/Users/*/Documents/Arduino/fastLEDcompressed/fastLEDcompressed.ino:39: undefined reference to `WS2812::setOutput(unsigned char)'
/var/folders/fr/vj8c52911yg97mycb0d8xjk00000gn/T//ccoFxRCe.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `loop':
/Users/*/Documents/Arduino/fastLEDcompressed/fastLEDcompressed.ino:44: undefined reference to `WS2812::set_crgb_at(unsigned int, cRGB)'
/Users/*/Documents/Arduino/fastLEDcompressed/fastLEDcompressed.ino:45: undefined reference to `WS2812::sync()'
/var/folders/fr/vj8c52911yg97mycb0d8xjk00000gn/T//ccoFxRCe.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_LED':
/Users/*/Documents/Arduino/fastLEDcompressed/fastLEDcompressed.ino:31: undefined reference to `WS2812::WS2812(unsigned int)'
/var/folders/fr/vj8c52911yg97mycb0d8xjk00000gn/T//ccoFxRCe.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_D_LED':
/Users/*/Documents/Arduino/fastLEDcompressed/fastLEDcompressed.ino:31: undefined reference to `WS2812::~WS2812()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.
```

The code compiles and runs just fine when using `#include` rather than writing it directly in the sketch.

Comment: "_The code compiles and runs just fine when using `#include` rather than writing it directly in the sketch._" - In which file are `WS2812`'s member functions defined? Are they inside a library that you haven't included or in a `.cpp` file that you forgot to add to the sketch?

Comment: I see that you now have accepted an answer which says exactly what I said in my answer. You disagreed with my answer saying "_The code compiles and runs just fine when using `#include` rather than writing it directly in._" - What changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of [function prototypes](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-user-defined-functions) without definition.

For example

```
void setOutput(uint8_t pin);
```

Here `setOutput` is declared as a method of WS2812, but the function is not defined anywhere, seems like you are missing the `.cpp` file where all this functions are specified, you can copy them at the end of the file and it should run ok.